# Snakemake Fastqc: "Multiple run or shell keywords in rule run_fastqc."

Tags: rna-seq, python, snakemake, quality-control, fastqc

I am trying to check the quality of RNA-Seq data from Illumina using fastqc in snakemake in a conda environment. I get the error "Multiple run or shell keywords in rule run_fastqc".

Snakefile:

```
rule run_fastqc:
    input:
        "/[RNA fastq file path]/well01_S001_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "./[out path]/well01_S001_L001_R1_001.fastqc.html",
        "./[out path]/well01_S001_L001_R1_001.fastqc.zip"
    wrapper:
        "0.79.0/bio/fastqc"
    shell:
        "fastqc {input} --outdir=./[out path]/"
```

I've also tried:

```
...
    shell:
        "fastqc {input} -o ./[out path]/"
...
    shell:
        "fastqc -o ./[out path]/ {input}"
...
    shell:
        "fastqc {input}"
        "fastqc -o ./[out path]/"
...
    shell:
        "fastqc {input} > -o ./[out path]/"
```

Code:

```
snakemake --cores 1 well01_S001_L001_R1_001.fastqc.html well01_S001_L001_R1_001.fastqc.zip
```

Output:

```
SyntaxError in line 9 of /[path to Snakefile]/Snakefile:
Multiple run or shell keywords in rule run_fastqc. (Snakefile, line 9)
```

When I run fastqc alone (not in snakemake), it works and I get the two output files. How can I get snakemake to work?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the manual, it looks like you are supposed to use just the `wrapper`, not combine the `wrapper` with a `shell`. Can you show me an example of such combined usage?

The error seems to suggest that the wrapper already has a `shell` directive that you `shell` conflicts with.

Comment: Thank you! In Output, I also had to remove the "./[out path]/" before the output file name, I guess the "--outdir" in Shell is sufficient. I got the files but still received the error: "Job Missing files after 5 seconds:
well01_S001_L001_R1_001.fastqc.html
well01_S001_L001_R1_001.fastqc.zip
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Job id: 0 completed successfully, but some output files are missing. 0" and I also waited for 60s and got the same error.